# t-SNE visualization getting (Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "factor")

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, multivariate-testing

I'm new to R and I'm trying to do a PAM clustering analysis and visualize the results via t-SNE. However, I keep getting this error `Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "factor"`.
The problem is I'm working with `chr` type of values as well as numeric. I've been trying to do the cluster analysis without getting rid of the chr and so I used the PAM method listed here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/06/clustering-mixed-data-types-in-r/

This is my data:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  country   health_expen gdp_pc life_exp healthsoc_empl
  <chr>            <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>
1 Australia        5130. 52669.     82.9           68  
2 Austria          5624. 58076.     82             53.0
3 Belgium          5353. 54278.     82.1           56.4
4 Canada           5190. 49299.     82.3           59.9
5 Chile            2297. 25189.     80.6           26.5
6 Colombia         1293. 15662.     76.6           18.4
```

and this is what I've been trying to do, where 'df2' is my data:

```
#cluster interpretation
pam_fit <- pam(gower_dist, diss = TRUE, k = 2)
pam_results <- df2 %>%
dplyr::select(-country) %>%
mutate(cluster = pam_fit$clustering) %>%
group_by(cluster) %>%
do(the_summary = summary(.))
pam_results$the_summary

df2[pam_fit$medoids, ]
```

```
#visualize variables with t-distributted stochastic neigbourhood embedding
tsne_obj<- Rtsne(gower_dist, is_distance = TRUE,dims = 3, perplexity = 1)
tsne_data <- tsne_obj$Y %>%
data.frame() %>%
setNames(c("X", "Y")) %>%
mutate(cluster = factor(pam_fit$clustering),name = df2$country)

ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y), data = tsne_data) +
geom_point(aes(color = cluster))
```

But as I said, I get an error because of the object of class "factor". What should I do?

Comment: Do you have multiple points per country or is it just one point per country?

Comment: What happens if you run all the code block togheter? I suspect you selected a line and accidentally run it.